$L_1$ norm of $f\in L^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$ compactly supported and its change of variable
Let $M\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ be an invertible matrix, denote its induced linear map on $\mathbb{R}^n$ also by $M$, and let $f\in L^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$ be compactly supported.
I am wondering if we can say something about the $L^1$ distance $||f-|\mathrm{det}(M)| (f\circ M)||_1$? The associated operator on $L^1$ with
$$Af=f-|\mathrm{det}(M)| (f\circ M)$$
is a linear bounded operator. Therefore,
$$||f-|\mathrm{det}(M)| (f\circ M)||_1=||Af||_1 \leq ||A||\,||f||_1.$$
Now the problem becomes the calculation of $||A||$, which basically leads me in circles.
The problem arises from a Markov chain model, where the $f$ are in the domain of the associated Laplace operator and $f-|\mathrm{det}(M)| (f\circ M)$ is the result of the action of one step of the forward semigroup on the marginal distributions.

"it is non-linear" I'm not sure I understand this sentence. The operator $A$ is actually linear.

I think $| A| = 2$ for $A\neq Id$ (and $|A| = 0$ trivially if $A = Id$).

@AlekseiKulikov Do you mean $M\not=Id$ and $M=Id$?

@AlekseiKulikov could you elaborate? Why should the norm be independent of $M$ if $M\neq Id$? We can fix that $||A||\leq 2$ by the triangular inequality but how do we get to equality? The second case is true, I agree.

Yes, I meant $M$, sorry. If $M\neq Id$ there is a vector $v$ such that $Mv\neq v$. Pick a function $f$ which is supported in a tiny vicinity of $v$, then the supports of $f$ and $f\circ M$ will not intersect.
